# Windows 10 automatic repair loop not showing mouse

Tags: windows, mouse, automation, system-restore

I upgraded my pc to windows 10 from windows 7.
Everything is installed fine. I signed into the microsoft account and i set the pin.
After that I rebooted pc and showed it me this:
Your pc did not start correctly
Press 'Restart' to restart your pc, which can sometimes fix the problem. You can also press "Advanced options" to try other options to repair your pc.

The problem is that it not showing me the mouse. So i can't press the buttons. Any ideas how to fix this? I tried to change mouse, but problem has not solved.

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Use the Tab key and/or your arrow keys to move between options, and use the Enter key to select the highlighted option.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: I believe that's the answer — why don't you post it as such?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Use keyboard also not working.

Comment: Have you tried another keyboard?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve this problem:

1. Create installation media on USB drive on another comuputer using `Media Creation Tool`.
2. Put the USB drive into PC, set first boot device to USB-HDD and mouse is working.